# Send just a string from $.ajax to c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is supposedly very easy but for some reason it has taken me about 2 hours and countless searches and nothing is working

I am trying to call a WebMethod from ajax, and it works quite well.
As soon as I try to change the c# function to accept parameters and send one from ajax everything fails

Code:
c#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetBGsForSelectedCrop(string cropName)
{
    return "asdasd";
}
```

jquery:

```
$().ready(function () {

        $("#Result").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetBGsForSelectedCrop",
                data: "Wheat",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                    alert(msg.d);
                    console.log(msg)
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I have tried `datatype: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, and tried without both and `datatype: "string"` and `datatype: "text"`, `GET`, `data: "{'ABCD'}`, `data:{"cropName: Wheat"}`, and `data: json.Stringify("Wheat")`.

I get undefined for `msg.d` and sometimes HTTP error 500 if I take it too far.

What am I missing? It is just a simple task and should've been done in seconds..

Comment: 500 error is a server error so something wrong there. Try setting `dataType:'text', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, and `data:{"cropName": "Wheat"}` all of them in your ajax settings.

Comment: You should also use stringify to encode your data correctly:  `data: JSON.stringify({ cropName: "Wheat" })`

Comment: Both of your answers combined worked for me except datatype: 'json' not 'text'
But why would i need to stringify a string?

Comment: @AngelicCore see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)  for the explenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the guys in the comments says, you need to change your code for:

```
$("#Result").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetBGsForSelectedCrop",
                data: JSON.stringify({ cropName: "Wheat" }),
                dataType:'text', 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                    alert(msg.d);
                    console.log(msg)
                }
            });
        });
```

Your error is the data is no good encoded, and you are missing the datatype.

[What is the stringfy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) It Convert any value to JSON.

Comment: Althought I have tried it as well, but Why do I need to stringify a string?

Comment: @AngelicCore It is because you are not dealing with string types, you are dealing with JSON. Your string needs to be in the correct format for ajax to be able to identify it as the "string" needed for your controller.  After stringifying into ajax, your controller is now aware of the value of cropName.